# PHP GD cut Triangle from Picture

Tags: php, image, gd

Guidelines: Using PHP and GD library

I have ordinary pictures (png|gif|jpeg) and want to cut out triangles.
To facilitate lets assume we want to cut images in 4 parts, each triangle starting from the 
center. You got it?

[image: Illustration rectangle to 4 triangles]

Painting triangles with GD goes like this:

```
<?php
//create a white canvas
$im = @imagecreate(500, 500) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
//triangle
$t1 = rand(0,400);
$t2 = rand(0,400);
$t3 = rand(10,100);
$t4 = rand(10,100);
$points = array(
$t1, $t2,
($t1+$t3), $t2,
$t1, ($t2+$t4)
);
$trcol = imagecolorallocate($im, rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255));
imagefilledpolygon($im, $points, 3, $trcol);
//make png and clean up
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

now we Actually want to CUT a triangle from an already existing picture. **I only know how to cut out a rectangle from an existing picture like this**:

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

[PHP GD imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) 
bool imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )

So how do we combine these two approaches to do what is intented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the x/y calculation could be more optimised with this, but it works for generating a png with top/right/bottom/left triangles from a given image, and outputting them as a png with transparent background -

```
// Set which triangle to generate
// top, right, bottom or left

$triangle   = 'top';

// Load source image

$src        = imagecreatefromjpeg ('Desert.jpg');

// Get image width/height

$srcWidth   = imagesx ($src);
$srcHeight  = imagesy ($src);

// Get centre position

$centreX    = floor ($srcWidth / 2);
$centreY    = floor ($srcHeight / 2);

// Set new image size and start x/y

switch ($triangle)
{

    case 'top':

        $destWidth  = $srcWidth;
        $destHeight = $centreY;

        $destSX     = 0;
        $destSY     = 0;

        break;

    case 'right':

        $destWidth  = $centreX;
        $destHeight = $srcHeight;

        $destSX     = $centreX;
        $destSY     = 0;

        break;

    case 'bottom':

        $destWidth  = $srcWidth;
        $destHeight = $centreY;

        $destSX     = 0;
        $destSY     = $centreY;

        break;

    case 'left':

        $destWidth  = $centreX;
        $destHeight = $srcHeight;

        $destSX     = 0;
        $destSY     = 0;

        break;

}

// Create the image

$dest           = imagecreatetruecolor ($destWidth, $destHeight);

// Copy from source

imagecopy ($dest, $src, 0, 0, $destSX, $destSY, $destWidth, $destHeight);

// OK... we now have the correctly sized rectangle copied over from the source image
// Lets cut it down and turn it into the triangle we want by removing the other triangles
// We remove the area by defining another colour as transparent and creating shapes with that colour

$colRed         = imagecolorallocatealpha ($dest, 255, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent ($dest, $colRed);

switch ($triangle)
{

    case 'top':

        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($centreX, $destHeight, 0, 0, 0, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($centreX, $destHeight, $destWidth, 0, $destWidth, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        break;

    case 'right':

        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array (0, $centreY, 0, 0, $destWidth, 0), 3, $colRed);
        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array (0, $centreY, 0, $destHeight, $destWidth, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        break;

    case 'bottom':

        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($centreX, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($centreX, 0, $destWidth, 0, $destWidth, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        break;

    case 'left':

        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($destWidth, $centreY, 0, 0, $destWidth, 0), 3, $colRed);
        imagefilledpolygon ($dest, array ($destWidth, $centreY, 0, $destHeight, $destWidth, $destHeight), 3, $colRed);
        break;

}

// Output new image

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng ($dest);

// Clean up

imagedestroy ($src);
imagedestroy ($dest);
```

Comment: hi Andy. Thank you for your contribution which is very good and smart. i like your approach even if it does not "cut out triangles". But maybe its not even possible to cut out other shapes than rectangulares from images using gd library with php. is it? i'm afraid that for such a  purpose we have to consultate imagemagick which is no default php install. though i wish there would be a smart workarround.

Comment: This solution, how would it be adapted to create a equilateral triangle for no matter what image? (scaling and quality loss isn't issue) ?? thanks